# How to query user with posts in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I want to display all post including the user who posted the post. I have a simple query which displays all post, and displays selected post using post id.

```
public function view_post($id)
    {
        $post = User::find($id);

        dd($post);

    }
```

This is working perfectly fine but I wanted to display all post with the user who posted the post. How can I do this in proper way?

Comment: Do you have any idea about laravel Eloquent model?

Comment: Did you defined the Models relationship? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Comment: This is CLEARLY EXPLAINED in the official Laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#eager-loading It would do you some good to read it before asking simple questions.

Comment: Read the book from Dayle Reese! It's very good for Laravel beginners. http://daylerees.com/codebright

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right now, it is possible to get the `Posts` by first getting the `User` then using that ID, getting the `Posts`. Note: this is not the recommended way of using Laravel with relationships:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$posts = Post::where("user_id", "=", $user->id)->get();
```

While this would work (assuming you had a model for `Post` with a `user_id` key), but the correct way is to define the relationship in the models. For this one, it would be `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` on `User` and `Post` respectfully. Here is your `User.php` model class:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = "users";

  public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany("Post");
  }
}
```

And make sure to define the inverse in your `Post.php` model class:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = "posts";

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("User");
  }
}
```

Lastly, you can query this relationship in your controller using the following:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$posts = $user->posts()->get();
```

This will also enforce integrity by forcing any updates/saves to use the right `user_id` key. There's some pretty extensive documentation on how to use the `Eloquent` style of database querying, check it out here:

[Laravel - Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)

Hope that helps!

**Edit**

To pass this to a view, add the following to your controller:

```
public function view_post($id){
    $user = User::find($id);
    $posts = $user->posts()->get();

    return View::make("view")->with(array("user" => $user, "posts" => $posts));
}
```

You will need a file in your `app/views` directory named (in this case) `view.blade.php` which "echos" all the information about the user and the posts:

```
<h2>User: {{ $user->id }} - {{ $user->email }}</h2>
<br/>
<h2>Posts:</h2>
@foreach($posts AS $post)
<p> {{ $post->id }}: {{ $post->content }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Etc etc. Note, I have no idea what columns your `users` and `posts` table has, but using `$user->column` or `$post->column` will echo the contents of that named column.

Here's the documentation for `Views and Responses`, which would help you with this issue:

[Laravel - Views and Responses](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses)

Comment: $posts = $user->posts()->get() this line will get all the post of a user right? how about if i only want to display a post with the user who posted it?

Comment: You pass both the `$user` and `$posts` to a view and process them there. I'll make a quick edit.

Comment: Now, if you want to show all posts with their user, do `Post::get()`, loop though each `$posts AS $post` and call `$post->user()->first` to get their info, such as name and email.

Comment: its ok i understand. its just that the method is kinda blurry. but now its much clearer thanks. i will try your code.

Comment: No problem! The first time I tried to do this is blew up pretty badly, but after you figure out what goes where, things just click and become second nature. Just keep it up, read the documents and most importantly experiment!

Comment: sure I will, Im enjoying this framework as i go deeper lol. thanks anyway

Comment: @TimLewis You’re pointing @seanacre in totally the wrong direction. He wants to get the user of a post: so `$post = $post->with('user')->find(1); $user = $post->user;` will do it.

Comment: @MartinBean I noticed that, hence the comment about 4 posts up; explains the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use also this.

```
public function($id){
$posts = Posts::where('uid','=',auth()->user()->id)->findOrFail($id);
return view('your_blade.php',compact('posts'));

OR either you can return this

return response()->json([$posts], 200);


}
```

Note: don't forgot to add trait also use App\Posts;