# Display all Posts from all Users

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

For example we have two tables

User and Post

User has many posts, but Post belongs to one User.

I want to display all the posts from the users on one page.

For example:
[posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/193fW.png)

So how can I display multiple posts from ALL the users on one page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query user with posts in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630850/how-to-query-user-with-posts-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

First: To get all users in you controller

```
$users = User::All();
```

then you can pass this **$users** to your view and loop through all the $users

```
foreach($users as $user){
   echo $user_email = $user->email;
   $user_posts = $user->post; //multiple posts, but need to establish relation
   echo "posts for this user";
   foreach($user_posts as $p){
       echo $p->title;
   }
}
```

Note: For big data it can be slower and not good practice. 
**User model** for users table: should have onetoMany relationship with post as

```
...........
...........
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id');
}
..........
..........
```

**Post model** for posts table

```
........
........
public function  user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
.........
.........
```

You need to put user_id field in you posts table.

Please also see about **lazy loading** and **Eager Loading**