# How to get stored data that's nested behind other models

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to display collected data in the view. But im having issues getting the data out of the database.

My database is build up as following:
User -> QRcodes -> Data

Im building a dashboard where the user can find all their QRcodes and where the user can click on "show more info". This needs to display the data that's collected.

The QRcodes has a "user_id"  to connect them to a user.

The Data has a "qr_id" to connect them to a qr-code.

The data is nestled in and I'm not sure how to retrieve this data.

Code here works, but it makes it so that every user can see anyones data:

```
$datas = saved::where('qr_id',$id)->get();
```

So, I need to display the info only if the auth id is the same as the qr_id in the save data.

Schema for the qr codes

```
Schema::create('qrs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('actualURL');
            $table->string('redirectURL');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('imageLocal');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Schema for the saved data

```
 Schema::create('saveds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('qr_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('ip')->nullable();
            $table->integer('clicks')->default(0);
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('province')->nullable();
            $table->string('currency')->nullable();
            $table->string('browserInfo')->nullable();
            $table->string('userOS')->nullable();
            $table->string('hostMachine')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('qr_id')->references('id')->on('qrs')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

Both the qr and saved data models have a relation. So they should be connected.

```
 public function qr()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\qr');
    }
```

Perhaps something like

```
$posts = $user->posts()->get();
```

should work like I saw in this post: [How to query user with posts in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630850/how-to-query-user-with-posts-in-laravel)

But I'm not sure how to implement that into my controllers.

Comment: Please edit the question and add all the model relationships defined.

Answer (score 0):

Since the relations returned from relation methods behave as query builders you can query relations just like anywhere else. Instead of:

```php
$datas = saved::where('qr_id',$id)->get();
```

do this:

```php
$datas = $user->saved()->where('qr_id',$id)->get();
```